# Preserving the State of a Drawer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have a stateful `Scaffold` widget, where the `body` contains a list of entities with various properties (e.g. shoes or cars) and `Drawer` widget, which is empty at first, except for two buttons at the bottom ("Cancel" and "Filter") and a FAB. The user can add various filters with the FAB (e.g. the user can add a shoesize-filter, or a color-filter).

The problem I have is the following: Let's say the user selects various filters and works with them (i.e. ticks checkboxes, enters a shoesize, changes sliders, etc.). When the user is ready to apply the filters, he can click the "Filter" button, which closes the `Drawer` (`onTap -> callback -> Navigator.of(context).pop()`). But when the user wants to go back, reopen the `Drawer`, and adjust one of the filters, it obviously doesn't work, since the widget is being rebuilt from scratch.

Currently, the way the filtering works is, once the "Filter" Button is pressed, all the various values from the added filters are collected into an object `FilterPackage`, which is then passed via `callback` to the `Scaffold` widget, which then applies the values from the `FilterPackage` to the list of entities.
One solution I came up with, would be feeding this `FilterPackage` object to the `Drawer` widget in its constructor, which would provide all the information necessary to rebuild the widget just how it has to be.

Is that a reasonable solution? I have already made some research, but struggled finding a solution on what would clearly be the best and recommended way to preserve the drawer's state. Using `PageStorage` / `PageStorageBucket` seems overly complicated for this case. Or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: You are talking about persistent app state management. There is no "clear best and recommended way" to go about doing this. There are a bunch of different packages and patterns you could employ to go about doing this, and all of them are equally valid (more or less). The question of if something is good or bad is not in which pattern to use, but in how you implement a specific pattern. (And to critique that, we would need to see code.)